# elasticsearch nested filters are not working as expected

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have documents like this in the elasticsearch:

```
{
    "_index": "4ccda045-3958-4773-bb34-7af26fa52f4e",
    "_type": "jira",
    "_id": "BIGHALF-23",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "Issue Key": "BIGHALF-23",
        "Issuetype Name": "Sub-task",
        "Project Name": "Big_Half ",
        "Project ID": "10500",
        "Project Key": "BIGHALF",
        "Workratio": -1,
        "Watch Count": 1,
        "Created": "2015-10-08T13:12:47",
        "Priority": "Medium",
        "Assignee Name": "german.solis",
        "Assignee EmailAddress": "german.solis@bighalf.io",
        "Assignee DisplayName": "German Solis",
        "Is Assignee Active": "true",
        "Assigne TimeZone": "America/Chicago",
        "Updated": "2015-10-19T19:21:22",
        "Issue Status": "Done",
        "sprint": [{
            "Sprint ID": "20",
            "Sprint State": "CLOSED",
            "Sprint Name": "Sprint 11",
            "Sprint StartDate": "2015-10-05T01:43:29",
            "Sprint EndDate": "2015-10-12T01:43:00",
            "Sprint CompleteDate": "2015-10-13T14:31:47"
        }, {
            "Sprint ID": "23",
            "Sprint State": "CLOSED",
            "Sprint Name": "Sprint 1",
            "Sprint StartDate": "2015-10-19T01:47:18",
            "Sprint EndDate": "2015-10-26T01:47:00",
            "Sprint CompleteDate": "2015-10-24T23:55:22"
        }, {
            "Sprint ID": "24",
            "Sprint State": "CLOSED",
            "Sprint Name": "Sprint 2",
            "Sprint StartDate": "2015-10-26T11:21:21",
            "Sprint EndDate": "2015-11-01T11:21:00",
            "Sprint CompleteDate": "2015-11-01T23:06:45"
        }],
        "Creator Name": "fernando.velazquez",
        "Creator EmailAddress": "fernando.velazquez@bighalf.io",
        "Creator DisplayName": "fernando.velazquez",
        "Creator Active": "false",
        "Creator TimeZone": "America/Chicago",
        "Reporter Name": "fernando.velazquez",
        "Reporter EmailAddress": "fernando.velazquez@bighalf.io",
        "Reporter DisplayName": "fernando.velazquez",
        "Reporter Active": "false",
        "Reporter TimeZone": "America/Chicago",
        "Aggregate Progress": 0,
        "Aggregate Progress Total": 0,
        "Progress": 0,
        "Progress Total": 0
    }
}
```

Am applying filter like this using transport client.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "nested" : {
        "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
              "terms" : {
                "sprint.Sprint Name" : [ "Sprint 9" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "path" : "sprint"
      }
    }, {
      "terms" : {
        "Assignee DisplayName" : [ "Mateen Khan" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Even after applying filter Am getting data of other sprints also. which means am getting data for "sprint 7" as well as other sprints also. Am using transport client and also Am performing few complex aggregations with in the same query.

Mappings:

```
{
  "4ccda045-3958-4773-bb34-7af26fa52f4e": {
    "mappings": {
      "jira": {
        "properties": {
          "Aggregate Progress": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Aggregate Progress Total": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Aggregate Progress percent": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Aggregate Time Estimate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Aggregate Time Original Estimate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Aggregate Timespent": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Assigne TimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Assignee DisplayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Assignee EmailAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Assignee Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Created": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "Creator Active": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Creator DisplayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Creator EmailAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Creator Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Creator TimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Description": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Is Assignee Active": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Issue Key": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Issue Status": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Issuetype Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Priority": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Progress": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Progress Percent": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Progress Total": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Project ID": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Project Key": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Project Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Reporter Active": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Reporter DisplayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Reporter EmailAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Reporter Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Reporter TimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Sprint Issue Points": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Summary": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Time Estimate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Time Original Estimate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Time Tracking Original Estimate": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Time Tracking Original Estimate Seconds": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Time Tracking Remaining Estimate": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Time Tracking Remaining Estimate Seconds": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Time Tracking Time Spent": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Time Tracking Time Spent Seconds": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Updated": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "Watch Count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Workratio": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "sprint": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "Sprint CompleteDate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "Sprint EndDate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "Sprint ID": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "Sprint Name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "Sprint StartDate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "Sprint State": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post the mapping?

Comment: Hi. I have updated the mappings.

Comment: Maybe the mapping you think your index is using, is not the real one. I tested your mapping and your sample data and it works for me.

Comment: Hi Andrei,
The index is the real one Andrei. But we are performing aggregations on nested JSON and that too we have a sub group with in a group.  That is group by "sprint.Sprint Name" and further sub-group by "Issuetype Name". And on top of it we are applying filters. The index and mappings are correct but the out put is not getting filtered. It would be great if you can share your contact details so that I explain more clearly about the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try replacing `terms` in `must` clause by `match`?

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "nested" : {
        "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
              "match" : {
                "sprint.Sprint Name" : [ "Sprint 9" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "path" : "sprint"
      }
    }, {
      "terms" : {
        "Assignee DisplayName" : [ "Mateen Khan" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```